# powershell script code to remove quotation marks doesn't remove them when running on task scheduler

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, quotation-marks

I have a powershell script that exports to a csv and I inserted a line to remove the quotations. It works if I run the powershell manually, but the quotation marks remain if i run in task scheduler!!
Why does this happen?

```
#Output RESULTS to CSV 
$DataSet.Tables[0] | select "ID" , "date" | Export-Csv  $OuputFile -NoTypeInformation
set-content data.csv ((get-content data.csv) -replace '"')
```

Comment: Is data.csv actually the fullpath of the csv? If not then that's probably the issue.

Comment: Ah yes... of course..d'oh!. It would run as the file was in the same directory. I have changed it to the filepath and it works with the task scheduler. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to give you an alternative to what you already have, instead of exporting to CSV and then reading from the CSV and removing all *double-quotes* `"` you can use [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.1):

```
#Output RESULTS to CSV 
($DataSet.Tables[0] | Select-Object ID, Date |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"' |
Out-File C:\data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Output RESULTS to CSV 
$DataSet.Tables[0] | select "ID" , "date" | Export-Csv  $OuputFile -NoTypeInformation
set-content C:\data.csv ((get-content C:\data.csv) -replace '"')
```